# T sql select pivot by using inner join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have query as below

```
    SELECT  cpn.ProjectName ,
            COUNT(c.case_ID) AS 'Total' ,
            DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(ca.xdate), 0) - 1) AS Month
    FROM    cases c
            JOIN case_action ca ON c.case_ID = ca.case_ID
            INNER JOIN tblCaseProjectsNew cpn ON cpn.ID = c.Project_ID
            INNER JOIN reseller_user_profiles rup 
                ON rup.reseller_user_ID = c.reseller_user_ID
    WHERE   cpn.ID = 1
            AND ca.status_ID = 0
    GROUP BY 
         cpn.ProjectName ,
         DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(ca.xdate), 0) - 1)
```

Query result as below

**Project (column) -  Total (column) -  Month (column)**

```
Project1            2             April

Project1            6            February

Project1            3             March
```

**Question:**

How can i select query as below

**April (column) - February (column) - March (column)**

```
2                 6                 3
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: if you can share any code i can use thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    cpn.ProjectName, 
    count(case when month(ca.xdate) = 2 then c.case_ID end) as [February column],
    count(case when month(ca.xdate) = 4 then c.case_ID end) as [April column]
from cases c
    inner join case_action ca on c.case_ID=ca.case_ID 
    inner join tblCaseProjectsNew cpn on cpn.ID=c.Project_ID
    inner join reseller_user_profiles rup on 
       rup.reseller_user_ID=c.reseller_user_ID
where cpn.ID=1 and ca.status_ID=0
group by  cpn.ProjectName
```

Comment: thanks for aswer if i copy and paste your code to my side i get syntax error for "Incorrect syntax near 'c'." may you please share all code after that i will accept best answer thanks